# Dropping Rows and Combining CSVs

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, read.csv, readr

I have a large CSV (1.2M+ rows). The first row / cell (A1) is some random text I want to delete, and then I want to make the second row the header.

After that is done, I have two other CSVs I want to combine with this one.

I am able to read.csv in, but am not sure where to go from there.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Do you want to skip the first row of only the first csv file or of each of the three csv file?

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(list_of_files, read.csv))` given a character vector of path/file names will return a single frame with all data.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide a precise answer without seeing the data, but something along these lines might work for you.

```
df1 <- read.csv('/path/to/file_1.csv', skip = 1)
df2 <- read.csv('/path/to/file_2.csv', skip = 1)
df3 <- read.csv('/path/to/file_3.csv', skip = 1)

combined <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

write.csv(combined, 'output.csv')
```